# Autocomplete Select: Call another function

Tags: javascript, function, select, autocomplete, call

I am not an expert in coding so I know I probably made an obvious mistake. I used Autocomplete to create an input field with a list of suggestions. I am now trying to call a function when I click on the suggestions.

As of now I have

```
$(function () {
        var Input = $("#Input").autocomplete({
            source: list,
            select: function() {
                alert('changed');
                }
            });
            Input.autocomplete('option', 'change').call(Input);
        });
```

Instead of alert('changed') I want to call a function, but it is not working. I know I am doing it correctly because I am able to call other functions, but not the one I need. This is what the function looks like

```
function getVariable()
  {
    var variable = document.getElementById("Input");
    var name = variable.value; 

      if (name == "A124") {
          changetoA();
      } else if (name == "B735") {
          changetoB();
      } else {
          document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Empty";
      }              
  };
```

I thought the problem could be because I am using the function to call another one, so I tried putting the instructions in one single function, from changetoA() and changetoB to getVariable(). It's still not working.

**EDIT**

This is the HTML for my Input element

```
<div id="main">
 <input id="Input" type="text"> <br/>
 <input id ="enterButton" type="button" value="Enter" onClick="getVariable()">
</div>
```

Comment: Can you the HTML code for `Input` element?

Comment: I'm assuming  your code looks like: `select : function() {getVariable();}` ?

Comment: @Shilly Yes, that is what I wrote when I tried to call it

Comment: @IswantoSan I edited the post

Answer (score 0):

I tested the code here, and the `getVariable` function was called. But, since `document.getElementById("Input").value` was not updated yet, we will always fall on the `else`... that gives the impression that nothing happend.

You may change `getVariable` to receive the `name` from `args.item.value`.
And remove this line: `Input.autocomplete('option', 'change').call(Input);`.

```js
function changetoA()
{
 alert('changeToA');
}

function changetoB()
{
 alert('changeToB');
}
  
$(function () {
 var Input = $("#Input").autocomplete({
  source: ['A124', 'B735'],
  select: function(s,e) {
   getVariable(e.item.value);
   }
  });
  //Input.autocomplete('option', 'change').call(Input);
});
  
function getVariable(name)
{
  if (name == "A124") {
   changetoA();
  } else if (name == "B735") {
   changetoB();
  } else {
   document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Empty";
  }              
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="main">
<input id="Input" type="text"> <br/>
<input id ="enterButton" type="button" value="Enter" onClick="getVariable()">
```

Comment: I added   `source:list`  (that is what I called my autocomplete list)   and     `select: function() {getVariable(planeName);}`.

When I click on the input field the whole list appears but I can't click on the values. I can when instead of `getVariable()` I use `changetoA()` or `changetoB()`

Comment: My mistake! I did not saw that list~